# Problema con la visualización de un JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo un programa para calcular figuras geométricas, pero el problema es que el primer *JFrame* aparece minimizado y vacío. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Esto tengo en el `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Principal prp=new Principal();
    prp.setVisible(true);
    prp.setTitle("Sistema De Calculos De Figuras Geometricas");
    prp.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

La clase `Principal` es un *JFrame* más, en el cual se muestra un menú. En el menú ítem le puse esto lo siguiente:

Clase `Principal`:

```
   public void Principal() {
    initComponents();
  }
```

aqui es el llamado a Figuras 
     fg=new Figuras();

```
private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    int seleccion = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(new JDialog(),
       "Desea calcular figuras geometricas","Anuncio",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    if(seleccion == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
        fg.setVisible(true);
        fg.setTitle("Figuras Geometricas");
        fg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

hasta ahí seria lo que es el JFrame principal, el JFrame figuras tiene la parte de los cálculos y después en otra clase esta la parte lógica

a continuación esta la clase datos y la parte lógica la borre simplemente, dejando en claro que si saco el **void** sigue el problema que aparece minimizado y vacio

```
public void Datos(){
}

double Radio, Altura, Area, Volumen, g,g2; 
public void getFiguras(){
 int eleccion = Figuras.Figuras.getSelectedIndex();

 switch(eleccion){
     case 0:
     case 1
     case 2:

 }
}
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tu constructor esta mal, ya que no va el `void`porque es un Constructor.

```
public Principal() {
    initComponents();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

bien eso ha servido, ahora sucede que mi segundo JFrame queda vacio, es decir, le pasa lo mismo que al anterior y he modificado tambien mi constructor en figuras que ha quedado asi: 
y`public Figuras() {
 }
// lo que sigue a continuación es el llamado
  Datos dts=new Datos();`

en la parte de datos, la parte lógica queda así mi constructor

```
  public void Datos(){

} 
    public void getFiguras(){
```

y el método bajo el constructor

Comment: Veo que el constructor de datos tiene un void cuando no lo deberia tener, ya que si lo tiene ya no seria constructor, podrias editar tu pregunta y compartir mas codigo para ver en que te puedo ayudar.